# LLVM opt removes all my code (but runs correctly when unoptimized)

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, compiler-optimization, llvm-ir

I'm trying out building a compiler with LLVM (inkwell crate in rust) by implementing a Brainf*** compiler/jit, dumping a main and a program function into a module and compiling. Both the JIT engine with *"OptimizationLevel::Aggressive"* and unoptimized external compilation (see below for the steps) seem to work and Brainf*** programs of significant size (drawing mandelbrot, embedded oop and other example programs) run correctly, but enabling any optimization level in LLVM *opt*  reduces the code to a **wrong** "constant expression".

An example: the following Brainf*** program `>++++++[<++++++++>-]<.` *should* print out the letter `0` (loading 6 * 8 = 48 = ASCII '0' into stack location 0 and then print). My compiler generates the following unoptimized LLVM IR module:

```
; ModuleID = 'my_module'
source_filename = "stdin"

define void @program(i8* %0) {
entry:
  %index = alloca i32, align 4 ;  allocate index
  ;  increment index `>`
  %offset = load i32, i32* %index, align 4
  %incremented = add i32 %offset, 1
  store i32 %incremented, i32* %index, align 4
  ;  increment cell `+` (6 times) ...
  %1 = load i32, i32* %index, align 4
  %2 = getelementptr i8, i8* %0, i32 %1
  %3 = load i8, i8* %2, align 1
  %4 = add i8 %3, 1
  store i8 %4, i8* %2, align 1
  %5 = load i32, i32* %index, align 4
  %6 = getelementptr i8, i8* %0, i32 %5
  %7 = load i8, i8* %6, align 1
  %8 = add i8 %7, 1
  store i8 %8, i8* %6, align 1
  %9 = load i32, i32* %index, align 4
  %10 = getelementptr i8, i8* %0, i32 %9
  %11 = load i8, i8* %10, align 1
  %12 = add i8 %11, 1
  store i8 %12, i8* %10, align 1
  %13 = load i32, i32* %index, align 4
  %14 = getelementptr i8, i8* %0, i32 %13
  %15 = load i8, i8* %14, align 1
  %16 = add i8 %15, 1
  store i8 %16, i8* %14, align 1
  %17 = load i32, i32* %index, align 4
  %18 = getelementptr i8, i8* %0, i32 %17
  %19 = load i8, i8* %18, align 1
  %20 = add i8 %19, 1
  store i8 %20, i8* %18, align 1
  %21 = load i32, i32* %index, align 4
  %22 = getelementptr i8, i8* %0, i32 %21
  %23 = load i8, i8* %22, align 1
  %24 = add i8 %23, 1
  store i8 %24, i8* %22, align 1
  ;  ...done.
  ;  goto branch condition
  br label %cond0

cond0:                                            ; preds = %block0, %entry
  ;  conditional `[`
  %offset1 = load i32, i32* %index, align 4
  %ptr = getelementptr i8, i8* %0, i32 %offset1
  %cell = load i8, i8* %ptr, align 1
  %25 = icmp eq i8 %cell, 0
  ;  jump to after matching `]` if cell is zero
  br i1 %25, label %after0, label %block0

block0:                                           ; preds = %cond0
  ;  decrement index `<`
  %offset2 = load i32, i32* %index, align 4
  %decremented = sub i32 %offset2, 1
  store i32 %decremented, i32* %index, align 4
  ;  increment current cell `+` (8 times) ...
  %26 = load i32, i32* %index, align 4
  %27 = getelementptr i8, i8* %0, i32 %26
  %28 = load i8, i8* %27, align 1
  %29 = add i8 %28, 1
  store i8 %29, i8* %27, align 1
  %30 = load i32, i32* %index, align 4
  %31 = getelementptr i8, i8* %0, i32 %30
  %32 = load i8, i8* %31, align 1
  %33 = add i8 %32, 1
  store i8 %33, i8* %31, align 1
  %34 = load i32, i32* %index, align 4
  %35 = getelementptr i8, i8* %0, i32 %34
  %36 = load i8, i8* %35, align 1
  %37 = add i8 %36, 1
  store i8 %37, i8* %35, align 1
  %38 = load i32, i32* %index, align 4
  %39 = getelementptr i8, i8* %0, i32 %38
  %40 = load i8, i8* %39, align 1
  %41 = add i8 %40, 1
  store i8 %41, i8* %39, align 1
  %42 = load i32, i32* %index, align 4
  %43 = getelementptr i8, i8* %0, i32 %42
  %44 = load i8, i8* %43, align 1
  %45 = add i8 %44, 1
  store i8 %45, i8* %43, align 1
  %46 = load i32, i32* %index, align 4
  %47 = getelementptr i8, i8* %0, i32 %46
  %48 = load i8, i8* %47, align 1
  %49 = add i8 %48, 1
  store i8 %49, i8* %47, align 1
  %50 = load i32, i32* %index, align 4
  %51 = getelementptr i8, i8* %0, i32 %50
  %52 = load i8, i8* %51, align 1
  %53 = add i8 %52, 1
  store i8 %53, i8* %51, align 1
  %54 = load i32, i32* %index, align 4
  %55 = getelementptr i8, i8* %0, i32 %54
  %56 = load i8, i8* %55, align 1
  %57 = add i8 %56, 1
  store i8 %57, i8* %55, align 1
  ;  ...done.
  ;  increment index `>`
  %offset3 = load i32, i32* %index, align 4
  %incremented4 = add i32 %offset3, 1
  store i32 %incremented4, i32* %index, align 4
  ;  decrement cell `-`
  %offset5 = load i32, i32* %index, align 4
  %ptr6 = getelementptr i8, i8* %0, i32 %offset5
  %cell7 = load i8, i8* %ptr6, align 1
  %dec_cell = sub i8 %cell7, 1
  store i8 %dec_cell, i8* %ptr6, align 1
  ;  unconditional jump `]` to matching `[`
  br label %cond0

after0:                                           ; preds = %cond0
  ;  decrement index `<`
  %offset8 = load i32, i32* %index, align 4
  %decremented9 = sub i32 %offset8, 1
  store i32 %decremented9, i32* %index, align 4
  ;  print current cell `.`
  %offset10 = load i32, i32* %index, align 4
  %ptr11 = getelementptr i8, i8* %0, i32 %offset10
  %cell12 = load i8, i8* %ptr11, align 1
  %58 = sext i8 %cell12 to i32
  %print = call i32 @putchar(i32 %58)
  ;  return
  ret void
}

declare i32 @putchar(i32) ; libc extern

declare i32 @getchar()    ; libc extern

define i32 @main() {
entry:
  ;  allocate bf stack
  %0 = trunc i64 100000 to i32
  %mallocsize = mul i32 %0, ptrtoint (i8* getelementptr (i8, i8* null, i32 1) to i32)
  %stack = tail call i8* @malloc(i32 %mallocsize)
  call void @llvm.memset.p0i8.i64(i8* align 1 %stack, i8 0, i64 100000, i1 false)
  ;  call compiled bf function
  call void @program(i8* %stack)
  ;  return EXIT_SUCCESS
  ret i32 0
}

declare noalias i8* @malloc(i32)

; Function Attrs: argmemonly nofree nounwind willreturn writeonly
declare void @llvm.memset.p0i8.i64(i8* nocapture writeonly, i8, i64, i1 immarg) #0

attributes #0 = { argmemonly nofree nounwind willreturn writeonly }
```

This module runs both through LLVMJIT as well as the following compile commands (with out.ll being this file):

```
llc out.ll -o out.asm
clang out.asm -o out
./out
-- 0
```

but as soon as I add an optimizer pass:

```
opt out.ll --O1 -S -o opt.ll
llc opt.ll -o opt.asm
clang opt.asm -o opt
./opt
--
```

the program doesn't work and the following (obviously wrong) "optimized" module is generated:

```
; ModuleID = 'out.ll'
source_filename = "stdin"

; Function Attrs: nofree nounwind
define void @program(i8* nocapture %0) local_unnamed_addr #0 {
entry:
  store i8 0, i8* %0, align 1
  %print = call i32 @putchar(i32 0)
  ret void
}

; Function Attrs: nofree nounwind
declare noundef i32 @putchar(i32 noundef) local_unnamed_addr #0

; Function Attrs: nofree nounwind
define i32 @main() local_unnamed_addr #0 {
entry:
  %print.i = call i32 @putchar(i32 0) #1
  ret i32 0
}

attributes #0 = { nofree nounwind }
attributes #1 = { nounwind }
```

Considering that the optimizer happily removes my code I must have violated some assumptions of the SSA code, but I can't figure out which. I alloca'd the only mutable variable (to avoid phi nodes) and I think my getelementptr and branch logic is correct; I also played around with different linkage flags to see if something changes, but I think I must have those correct, because else the CRT wouldn't find the main function. opt -print-after-all also didn't really help me understand the optimizations.

Could somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

(PS: FYI going directly through `clang -O<N> out.ll -o out` without opt gives the same results.)

Comment: What you want is probably the `-print-after-all` option, which tells you precisely which pass is removing what.

Comment: @arnt I did try that but the output is tbh such an overload nightmare that I couldn't figure out where exactly something went wrong.

Comment: Btw I added the rust flag because this was generated in rust with the inkwell crate.

Comment: I see. Well, making sense of the nightmare should take about ten seconds. Run `opt -print-after-all … | less` then press `G?call` and hit return. G takes you to the end, ?call takes you up to the last line that contains the four characters "call". Now you're looking at the last pass that still has the call, the next pass will be the one that removes it. The name of that pass tells you what the pass does. Knowing that, guessing why it removed that particular instruction is usually simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  %index = alloca i32, align 4 ;  allocate index
  ;  increment index `>`
  %offset = load i32, i32* %index, align 4
```

`%offset` is now `undef` because you never stored a value into the alloca'd memory.

If you check `opt -sroa` over your code, you can see this:

```
define void @program(i8* %0) {
entry:
  %incremented = add i32 undef, 1
  %1 = getelementptr i8, i8* %0, i32 %incremented
```

and so on.